# Can't find variable: page in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm beginner in test, both in Unit Test and UI Test

I'm trying to create a UI test for my login page using following code:

```
console.log("Teste de Login");

var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://localhost/login', function(status) {
    console.log("Page loadeed");

    if(status === "success") {
        page.render('example1.png');
    }

    page.evaluate(function() {
        // $("#numeroUsuario").val("99734167");
        document.getElementById('numeroUsuario').value = "99734167";
        page.render('exampl2.png');

        // $("#formLogin").submit();
        page.render('example3.png');
    });

    phantom.exit();
});
```

But this code returns the following error:

```
> phantomjs.exe ./testLogin.js
Teste de Login
Page loadeed
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: page

  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():4
  phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():8
```

Where element `$("#numeroUsuario")` exists. What have I done wrong?

Comment: If you're showing all your code, the error is on line 8, which would be `page.render('example1.png');`, and indicates that global `var page` is not defined. You could check that by examining the response to the `create()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure that in a `page.evaluate` environment, you can't reference anything from the Phantom script.

In your case, you could actually have multiple evaluate calls:

```
console.log("Teste de Login");

var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://localhost/login', function(status) {
    console.log("Page loadeed");

    if(status === "success") {
        page.render('example1.png');
    }

    page.evaluate(function() {
        // $("#numeroUsuario").val("99734167");
        document.getElementById('numeroUsuario').value = "99734167";
    });

    page.render('exampl2.png');

    page.evaluate(function() {
        // $("#formLogin").submit();
    });

    page.render('example3.png');

    phantom.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 11):

The [documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) says the following about the page context (emphasis mine):

> The execution is **sandboxed**, the web page has no access to the `phantom` object and it **can't probe its own setting**.

This means that variables defined outside of the `page.evaluate()` callback function are not accessible inside of it. It also means that `this` refers to the `window` object.

You can of course split the `page.evaluate()` call into multiple calls and move the move the calls that use outer variables in between the `page.evaluate()` calls like [Platinum Azure showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32954904/1816580), but this doesn't work if you want to call some PhantomJS function from inside of a callback inside of the `page.evaluate()` callback.

The solution would be to use the [`window.callPhantom` and `page.onCallback` pair](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-callback.html). This is perfect for asynchronous functions:

```
var renderId = 0;
page.onCallback = function(data){
    console.log("Callback: " + data.type);
    if (data.type === "exit") {
        phantom.exit();
    } else if (data.type === "render") {
        page.render(data.fname || ("screenshot_" + (renderId++) + ".png"));
    }
};

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg){
    console.log("remote> " + msg);
};

var getUrl = "http://example.com";
page.open(url, function(){
    page.evaluate(function(getUrl){
        $.get(getUrl, "", function(data){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            window.callPhantom({ type: "render" });
            window.callPhantom({ type: "exit" });
        });
    }, getUrl);
});
```

The exit might interfere with the previously triggered render operation. It surely is possible to delay the exit in that case by some fixed amount of time such as half a second:

```
if (data.type === "exit") {
    setTimeout(function(){
        phantom.exit();
    }, 500);
}
```

---

Furthermore it isn't possible to pass the `page` object into the page context, because only serializable objects can be passed in:

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the `evaluate` function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will *not* work!**

Comment: THIS is the answer!! Thanks!

Comment: To my knowlege this do not work anymore. If I have page in the onCallback method it dont know the variable

Comment: @PoulK.Sørensen Not sure what you mean. It might not work, if the exit happens during the render. It sure would be possible to add a small delay during exit.