# Recursively walk website pages with phantomjs

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, phantomjs

I have to go through all the pages from a website and check for an element on every page. This has to happen recursively, and I chose to do it with PhantomJS. So, I basically have this/such code in `main.js`:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

var allUrls = [];

var pageCheck = function(url) {

    page.open(url, function(success) {

        page.evaluate(function(allUrls, nextPage) {

            // crawl all links, and if they are from this site .. 
            // add them to the allUrls array .. 

            // then check the page for the element .. 

            // and go to next eventual page .. 
            setTimeout(nextPage, 250);

        }, allUrls, nextPage);

    });

};

var nextPage = function() {

    var nextUrl = allUrls.unshift();
    if(nextUrl) pageCheck(nextUrl);

};

pageCheck('http://example.com/');
```

and I call this with `phantomjs main.js`.

But I see messages that "Can't find variable ...". And when I cleared all of them - I see now `Can't find variable: pageCheck`

How am I supposed to do this? ... And what is all this stuff with PhantomJS scopes ?? ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't find variable: page in PhantomJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32954786/cant-find-variable-page-in-phantomjs)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but I got to that topic when at first `allUrls` and `nextPage` were not accessible inside `page.evaluate`. But I fixed those with passing them as parameters to `page.evaluate`. The problem is that there are two functions here, and they don't seem to see each other ?? ... or at least this is what it looks like to me ...

Comment: As I said in the end of my answer, you can't pass functions into the page context. The first part of my answer gives a workaround that works for your case.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to figure it out, thanks to @ArtjomB :)

Basically, my mistake was that I was trying to call global stuff from `page.evaluate`, while I had to use it only for `page` manipulation. So I changed the code to this/such one:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

var allUrls = [];

var pageCheck = function(url) {

    page.open(url, function(success) {

        var evalulation = page.evaluate(function() {

            // gather urls and check element .. 

            return {
                urls: ...,
                checkedElement: ...
            };

        });

        // manipulate the results from page.evaluate .. 
        someStuff(evalulation.urls);
        otherStuff(evalulation.checkedElement);

        // and THEN ... go to next eventual page .. 
        setTimeout(nextPage, 250);

    });

};

var nextPage = function() {

    var nextUrl = allUrls.unshift();
    if(nextUrl) pageCheck(nextUrl);
    else phantom.exit();

};

pageCheck('http://example.com/');
```