# Using callPhantom through karma runner

Tags: phantomjs, mocha.js, karma-runner

I've been trying to figure out how to execute the CallPhantom function when running a test through Karma. I've found two pages that seem to have the solution:

- https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher/issues/19
- [Take screenshot from Karma while running tests in PhantomJS 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34694765/take-screenshot-from-karma-while-running-tests-in-phantomjs-2)

But sadly it seems that I just cant seem to get the call to execute correctly. Nor can I seem to actually change the windowName which is more odd.

I created a repo to show where I'm currently at and to trim it down to just Karma, Phantom and Mocha so to get as pure of an example as I can. Hopefully someone can help!

https://github.com/rickyp-ms/example-karma-phantom-callPhantom-sendEvent/

Answer (score 0):

Found out the answer after posting to https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher/issues/19. Turns out that console.logs don't work so that was the only issue. It actually did end up working.

I've pushed up a new change as an example.